# Change color of stroke

Tags: java, colors, processing

I want to change the color of the *strokes* but I can't figure out *how to do this correctly* I looked up a tutorial and it showed me the *hu* stuff in the code. That it changes the *hu* in the for loop but it just remains one color.. In my case yellowish

```
void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  colorMode(HSB);

}
float t = 0;
float tn = 0;

void draw(){
 background(0);

 translate(width / 2, height / 2);

  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  float hu = 0;


 beginShape();

 //add vertices...
 for(float theta = 0; theta <= 8 * PI; theta += 0.001){
   float rad = r(theta,
   1, //a
   1, //b
   sin(tn) * 0.1 + 5, //m
   cos(tn) / 2, //n1
   sin(t) * 0.5 + 0.5, //n2
   cos(t) * 0.5 + 0.5 //n3
   );
   float x = rad * cos(theta) * 50;
   float y = rad * sin(theta) * 50;
   stroke(hu, 255, 255);
   vertex(x,y);
       hu += 1;
    if(hu > 255){
      hu = 0;
    }
 }


 endShape();

 t += 0.1;
 tn += 0.1;
}



float r(float theta, float a, float b, float m, float n1, float n2, float n3){
  return pow(pow(abs(cos(m * theta / 4.0) / a), n2) + 
             pow(abs(sin(m * theta / 4.0) / b), n3), -1.0 / n1) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/beginShape_.html) for the `beginShape` function:

> The P2D and P3D renderers allow stroke() and fill() to be altered on a per-vertex basis, but the default renderer does not.

In other words, you can't change the stroke color like this with the default renderer. You could just use the `P2D` renderer instead:

```
size(500, 500, P2D);
```

If you need to use the default renderer for some reason, then you're going to have to draw the lines yourself instead of relying on the `vertex` function.